# Perl DBD can't connect to MySQL on a 64-bit machine

Tags: mysql, database, linux, perl, rhel

I am on `RHEL 5.5 64 bit` machine.

I installed [ActivePerl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActivePerl) 5.10 64 bit on the machine, upgrading the previous inbuilt Perl 5.8 64 bit. I have MySQL up and running and my PHP project is able to access it. My Perl file needs to access the same database using DBD, but it's not able to do that. I have verified that:

1. My MySQL service is up and running.
2. My user is present and the database along with data do exist.
3. I am able to access the data from the database via the shell MySQL client.

Following is my Perl script.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use DBI;


$dbh = DBI->connect( "DBI:mysql:go:super218:3306","root","NEWPASSWORD" ) or die "Couldn't connect to database: " . DBI->errstr;

my $sth = $dbh->prepare( "SELECT * FROM phones" )
      or die "Can't prepare SQL statement: $DBI::errstr\n";

$sth->execute or die "executing: $stmtA ", $dbh->errstr;

my @row;
while ( @row = $sth->fetchrow_array( ) ) {
      print "Row: @row\n";
  }
```

I am getting the following error with correct user and password :

```
DBI connect('go:super218:3306','root',...) failed: (no error string) at testdb.pl line 6
Couldn't connect to database:  at testdb.pl line 6.
```

I get the following error with incorrect user or password:

```
DBI connect('go:super218:3306','root1',...) failed: Access denied for user 'root1'@'localhost' (using password: YES) at testdb.pl line 6
Couldn't connect to database: Access denied for user 'root1'@'localhost' (using password: YES) at testdb.pl line 6.
```

How do I solve this? I guess the problem is at MySQL's end.

Comment: can you change `DBI:mysql:go:super218:3306` this to `DBI:mysql:go;host=super218`. Also add `use strict; use warnings;` to your script.+

Comment: @Devendra : can you please elaborate on use strict; and use warnings; how do I use them?

Comment: add after `#!/usr/bin/perl` i.e. on next line.before `use DBI;` refer [link](http://learnperl.scratchcomputing.com/tutorials/getting_started/) for `use strict;` and `use warnings;`

Answer (score 2):

Use single quotes generally in **database connection string, password string and sql query**,because these might give you error with double quotes.As double quotes is used for [interpolation](http://perlmeme.org/howtos/using_perl/interpolation.html).

Here's how I think you should write.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use DBI;
use DBD::mysql;

my $dbh = DBI->connect( 'DBI:mysql:go;host=super218','root','NEWPASSWORD' ,{ RaiseError => 1 } )or die "Couldn't connect to database";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare( 'SELECT * FROM phones');

$sth->execute;

while ( my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array() ) {
      print "Row: @row\n";
   }
```

Comment: Tried... issue stays the same. :( 

I tried the above script on a 32 bit RHEL machine. It works fine there.

Comment: @user1263746- that's some good question or issue raised by you.I hope some more experienced folks might be able to answer.One solution I guess is to use `64 bit DBD::mysql and DBI`. But still I am unaware of it.see if this [link](http://nxadm.wordpress.com/tag/dbdmysql/) helps.

Comment: @user1263746 - Is your `MySQL 64 bit`?

Comment: = Yes, my MySQL is 64 bit. I found a workaround and I will post it once I am able to confirm that its working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my guess.

Have you installed the mysql connector lib from mysql properly?

Have you specified the host?

Try this out:

```
  my $db        = 'database_name';
  my $srv       = 'localhost';
  my $user      = '***************';
  my $pass      = '***************';
  my $port      = '3306';
  my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:$db:$srv", $user, $pass, {'RaiseError' => 1, 'PrintError' => 1, 'AutoCommit' => 1 }) or die "Connection Failed: $db DB on $srv\n\t$DBI::errstr\n";
```

If this is not working, try to install an ODBC driver for your server and use that.

Comment: As you can see, the connection is actually established as mysql is able to verify a correct user...